# From a list of many dataframes. How can i get the df with the max and min lenght?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, if i have:

```
list=[df1,df2,df3,df4]
```

How can python identify and get the df with the maximum number of rows? or len
And if you have 2 dfs with the min or max value, it can take any of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `max()` function with a key that specifies the way you look at the magnitude of your data:

```
max_df = max(list_, key=len)
min_df = min(list_, key=len)
```

**NOTE** there is an implicit mistake in your code that you might wanna correct. you have overwritten the python keyword `list`. add an underscore for example to the end of it to avoid any unwanted error

***UPDATE:*** the `key=lambda x:len(x)` replaced by `key=len`, thanks to @rafaelc comment